# Freezing Header Row of a dynamic Grid

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a gridview that I'm creating dynamically. I'm adding it to my form at run-time (so my HTML source has no tags for it). I've managed to get the scroll bars, but my manager has asked that I freeze the header row while scrolling. A exhaustive hunt on the internet has only shown static gridview examples. I've tried to implement a common javascript solution, but get an error "Object required" flagging this line:

```
var gridWidth = grid.offsetWidth;
```

Here's my html source:

```
form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButtonExcelExport" runat="server"
        ImageUrl="~/css/images/icons/custom/Excel-16.gif" 
        ToolTip="Export to Excel" PostBackUrl="~/ErrorReportGrid.aspx" />


    <div id="Div1" runat="server" >
    </div>


</div>

<!-- javascript here -->
<script type = "text/javascript">
var GridId = "<%=ErrorCodeGrid.ClientID %>";
var ScrollHeight = 300;
window.onload = function() {
    var grid = document.getElementById(GridId);
    var gridWidth = grid.offsetWidth;
    var gridHeight = grid.offsetHeight;
    var headerCellWidths = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < grid.getElementsByTagName("TH").length; i++) {
        headerCellWidths[i] = grid.getElementsByTagName("TH")[i].offsetWidth;
    }

grid.parentNode.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
    var parentDiv = grid.parentNode;
    var table = document.createElement("table");

for (i = 0; i < grid.attributes.length; i++) {
        if (grid.attributes[i].specified && grid.attributes[i].name != "id") {
            table.setAttribute(grid.attributes[i].name, grid.attributes[i].value);
        }
    }

    table.style.cssText = grid.style.cssText;
    table.style.width = gridWidth + "px";
    table.appendChild(document.createElement("tbody"));
    table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].appendChild(grid.getElementsByTagName("TR") [0]);
    var cells = table.getElementsByTagName("TH");
    var gridRow = grid.getElementsByTagName("TR")[0];

for (i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
        var width;
        if (headerCellWidths[i] > gridRow.getElementsByTagName("TD")[i].offsetWidth) {
            width = headerCellWidths[i];
        }
        else {
            width = gridRow.getElementsByTagName("TD")[i].offsetWidth;
        }
        cells[i].style.width = parseInt(width - 3) + "px";
        gridRow.getElementsByTagName("TD")[i].style.width = parseInt(width - 3) + "px";
    }

parentDiv.removeChild(grid);
    var dummyHeader = document.createElement("div");
    dummyHeader.appendChild(table);
    parentDiv.appendChild(dummyHeader);
    var scrollableDiv = document.createElement("div");

if (parseInt(gridHeight) > ScrollHeight) {
        gridWidth = parseInt(gridWidth) + 17;
    }

scrollableDiv.style.cssText = "overflow:auto;height:" + ScrollHeight + "px;width:" + gridWidth + "px";
    scrollableDiv.appendChild(grid);
    parentDiv.appendChild(scrollableDiv);
}</script>
```

and here's my vb code:

```
Public ErrorCodeGrid As GridView

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    'Create dynamic grid
    ErrorCodeGrid = New GridView
    ErrorCodeGrid.ID = "ErrorCodeGrid"
    'form1.Controls.Add(ErrorCodeGrid)
    Div1.Attributes("Style") = "width: 930px; height: 280px; margin-top: 0px; overflow: auto"
    Div1.Controls.Add(ErrorCodeGrid)

    'Set datasource ID for dynamic grid / sets the data that is displayed
    If Session("strVariableA") = "SINGLEUSER" And Session("strVariableB") = "EMPTY" Then 'staff sees their personal error
        ErrorCodeGrid.DataSource = SqlDataSourceSingleUser
        strSQL = SqlDataSourceSingleUser.SelectCommand.Replace("@User_ID", "'" + Session("strVariableB") + "'")
    ElseIf Session("strVariableA") = "ALL_RECORDS" Then 'user selects the list item "All Records"
        If Session("strVariableB") = "READ" Then 'if user has READ access, sees everyone's errors
            ErrorCodeGrid.DataSource = SqlDataSourceErrorReports_Core_Data
            strSQL = SqlDataSourceErrorReports_Core_Data.SelectCommand.ToString
        Else 'user sees all errors but Provider Data's
            ErrorCodeGrid.DataSource = SqlDataSourceStaffNoUserID
            strSQL = SqlDataSourceStaffNoUserID.SelectCommand.ToString
        End If
    ElseIf Session("strVariableA") = "CATEGORY_DESCRIPTIONS" Then 'user selects the list item "Category Descriptions"
        ErrorCodeGrid.DataSource = SqlDataSourceErrorDescriptions
        strSQL = SqlDataSourceErrorDescriptions.SelectCommand.ToString
    ElseIf Session("strVariableA") = "ACTIVE_ERROR" Then 'user selects a list item within the Code dropdown
        ErrorCodeGrid.DataSource = SqlDataSourceActiveErrors
        strSQL = SqlDataSourceActiveErrors.SelectCommand.Replace("@Error_Code", "'" + Session("strVariableB") + "'")
    ElseIf Session("strVariableA") = "STAFF_MEMBER" Then 'manager sees the selected user's errors
        ErrorCodeGrid.DataSource = SqlDataSourceMgrSingleUser
        strSQL = SqlDataSourceMgrSingleUser.SelectCommand.Replace("@User_ID", "'" + Session("strVariableB") + "'")
    ElseIf Session("strVariableA") = "TEAM" Then 'manager sees the selected team's errors
        ErrorCodeGrid.DataSource = SqlDataSourceMgrTeam
        strSQL = SqlDataSourceMgrTeam.SelectCommand.Replace("@Team_Name", "'" + Session("strVariableB") + "'")
    End If
    ErrorCodeGrid.DataBind()

    'set gridview parameters
    ErrorCodeGrid.EmptyDataText = "You currently have no errors."
    ErrorCodeGrid.CellPadding = 2
    ErrorCodeGrid.AllowSorting = True
    ErrorCodeGrid.CellSpacing = 1
    ErrorCodeGrid.Height = Unit.Pixel(111)
    ErrorCodeGrid.Width = Unit.Pixel(2775)
    ErrorCodeGrid.RowStyle.Font.Size = 8

    'set gridview colors
    ErrorCodeGrid.ForeColor = Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(&H333333)
    ErrorCodeGrid.RowStyle.BackColor = Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(&HF7F6F3)
    ErrorCodeGrid.RowStyle.ForeColor = Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(&H333333)
    ErrorCodeGrid.AlternatingRowStyle.BackColor = Drawing.Color.White
    ErrorCodeGrid.AlternatingRowStyle.ForeColor = Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(&H284775)
    ErrorCodeGrid.HeaderStyle.BackColor = Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(&H5D7B9D)
    ErrorCodeGrid.HeaderStyle.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.White
    ErrorCodeGrid.HeaderStyle.Font.Bold = True
    ErrorCodeGrid.HeaderStyle.Font.Size = 8

End Sub
```

Comment: It seems that your **grid** object is null? put this on console and try to find is it null?

Comment: the commented area that says "datasource here." I have code that assigns the datasource, I just left it out because it lengthens the code. Should I just include it? *edit* I went ahead and added it in. When I run the code without the javascript. I pull in data, I just don't have a locked header row.

Comment: I put it on the console and ignored that error and the next one corresponding to "var gridHeight = grid.offsetHeight;".  It then falls on my for loop where it registers grid.getElementsByTagName("TH").length as null. Not sure, I know how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify an ID for the dynamic grid in order for it to have a ClientID.

```
    ErrorCodeGrid = New GridView
    ErrorCodeGrid.ID = "ErrorCodeGrid"
```

EDIT:  Some more insight since you said it didn't work for you.

Without specifying the ID I got this js output (I removed a bunch of your design attributes for clarification):

```
var GridId = "ctl02"; // Your ID may differ.
```

and the gridview:

```
table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;"
```

Notice there is no ID specification on the gridview so the javascript could not find it and I get a null reference.

Adding the ID I get this:

```
var GridId = "ErrorCodeGrid";
table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="ErrorCodeGrid" style="border-collapse:collapse;"
```

Notice that the IDs match.

If this does not work for you perhaps you are using an older version of asp.net than I am or something.  But bottom line these IDs need to match.

Another option if you can't get this to work.  Move your entire code into a function and pass in the GridId (this is a good idea anyway).  Then you can dynamically inject the calling code with the ClientId of the dynamic gridview.

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType, "FreezeHeader", "FreezeHeader(" & ErrorCodeGrid.ClientID & ");", True)
```

EDIT 2: 
Using the code above you need to change your javascript in your page.

Replace this code:

```
var GridId = "<%=ErrorCodeGrid.ClientID %>";
var ScrollHeight = 300;
window.onload = function() {
```

with this code:

```
var ScrollHeight = 300; // you could move this into the function as well.
var FreezeHeader = function(GridId) {
```

The Client Script Manager will just be outputting a call to this function.

Comment: I added 
    ErrorCodeGrid.ID = "ErrorCodeGrid" 
but it still doesn't work. I think I'm using ASP.NET 2.5. I'm trying your solution with clientscript.  While I'm comfortable making a traditional function, I'm not really familiar with scripts or script literal syntax. Do I need to translate that javascript to VB? From a few examples I've seen on the net, it suggests that I make the entire body of code a string without the tags. Am I way off base here?

Comment: No you don't translate the function to VB. All you are doing is calling the function using the Client Script Manager.  I will add some additional info.

Comment: What is the output you are getting in the HTML?  Do you have an id on the table?  Does it match the id you are outputting in the javascript?